# How to create a Lock in 2 timer tasks Java reliably (So will wait when other is running)

Tags: java, multithreading, locks

I am running 2 timer tasks. it's something like

```
@Autowired
private Insertion insertion;

@Autowired
private Updation updation;
```

1. insert some data in DB

   ```
   timer.schedule(insertion,1000,5000)

   public run() {
       if(!Updationhappening) {
           //start insertion
       }
       else {
          //wait
       }
   }
   ```
2. update that data with something

   ```
   timer.schedule(updation,1000,5000)

   if(!InsertionHappening) {
       //start updation
   } else {
       //wait
   }
   ```

However i want to pause the update when insertion is running .

I know maybe i can do this with a volatile variable or Locks but i am not able to get any implementation about this locking system. Can anyone suggest an example implementation between 2 different nodes

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your inputs Everyone

I found a solution to the issue 
i used REENTRANT Locks to solve the issue . made a static Lock object in A global file and made lock.tryLock() in both the file to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can order updates and inserts with `PriorityBlockingQueue` to process inserts with priority.

Comment: Arent priority queues for sending data . never used one. So i am not sure i dont understand what will be put and what will be fetched.or am i missing something and they are locking  something?

Comment: PriorityBlockingQueue Works on the logic that one thread has to add data(Thread 1) and one has to fetch data(Thread 2) and if queue is full or queue is empty the thread will be blocked.

However in my scenerio i want thread to be working unless there is a flag(If i take PriorityBlockingQueue that means if queue is empty start thread 2 and if queue has data stop thread 2 as thread 1 is working) 

This is just the opposite of priority queue.